# C Programming yes no loop with error catcher

Tags: c, loops

I am trying to get this yes no programme to work in a loop. I've checked the other users messages and there's only one which is poorly written and doesn't work properly.

So if the user types y or Y it installs and if they type n or N it exits out of the program. Also if they type w, m or any other letter that isn't y or n it goes back to the start and asks them again.

Not sure if its a while loop or a do while loop. The programme below works but doesn't have any loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char yn;

    printf("Do you want to install this programme? y/n: ");
    scanf("%c", &yn);

    if(yn == 'y' ||  yn == 'Y') {
        printf("Installing...\n");
    }
    else if(yn == 'n' || yn == 'N') {
        printf("Exiting programme!\n");
    }
    else {
        // Go back to the start/top of the programme!
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show one of your attempts at a loop so we can maybe see your misunderstanding and better help?

Comment: Are you using the `<Enter>` key?  That is a `char` too.  Code does not yet account for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

This is the code that works. Thanks to @govindparmar.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char yn;

    do {
    printf("Do you want to install this programme? y/n: ");
    scanf(" %c", &yn);
    }
    while(yn != 'n' && yn != 'N' && yn != 'y' && yn != 'Y');

    if(yn == 'n' ||  yn == 'N') {
    printf("Exiting programe!\n");
    }
    else {
    printf("Installing...\n");
    }

    printf("It works!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your code into a while-loop.

Something like:

```
while(1)
{
    printf("Do you want to install this programme? y/n: ");
    scanf("%c", &yn);

    if(yn == 'y' ||  yn == 'Y') {
        printf("Installing...\n");
        break;  // Stop the while-loop to end the program
    }
    else if(yn == 'n' || yn == 'N') {
        printf("Exiting programme!\n");
        break;  // Stop the while-loop to end the program
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add a `break` after the `printf("Installing programme...\n");` as well, shouldn't you?

Comment: @MichaelBeer It's there

Comment: Whats the 1 for in the while function while(1)?

Comment: Anything that is not 0 is considered true.  This is a way to make the loop infinite.

Answer (score 1):

The type of loop that makes most sense in this scenario is a `do`/`while` loop since getting a response from a user is something that should happen at least once and be tested for until a desired response is obtained from the user.

Also, using `tolower` or `toupper` on `yn` when checking for equality can eliminate the need to check both upper and lowercase.

```
do
{
     printf("Do you want to install this program? y/n: ");
     scanf(" %c", &yn);
}
while(tolower(yn) != 'n' && tolower(yn) != 'y');

if(tolower(yn) == 'n')
{
     printf("Exiting program\n");
}
else
{
     printf("Installing ...\n");
}
```

Comment: This is more my style at the moment! Thanks!

Comment: Do I need a library for the tolower like <stdio.h> to make this work?

Comment: @Code9dan include `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` for this code to work

Comment: I deleted the space before the `%c` so it looked like this `scanf("%c", &yn);`. The printf statement above printed twice. I put the space back in `scanf(" %c" &yn);` and it worked fine. Why does the space make the program work. Any help on this would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` can be used to capture the input. It has an advantage of being able to clear the input stream in case of too many characters or incorrect characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void) {
    char input[3] = "";//can hold one char a newline and a '\0'

    printf("Do you want to install this programme? y/n: ");

    do {
        printf ( "\nenter y or n\n:");
        if ( fgets ( input, sizeof input, stdin)) {
            if ( !strchr ( input, '\n')) {//is there a newline?
                while ( !strchr ( input, '\n')) {//call until newline is found to clear input
                    if ( !fgets ( input, sizeof input, stdin)) {
                        fprintf ( stderr, "\nEOF problem\n");
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
                input[0] = 0;
                printf ( "\ntoo many characters. try again.");
            }
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "\nEOF problem\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if ( input[0] == 'y' || input[0] == 'Y') {
            printf("Installing...\n");
        }
        if ( input[0] == 'n' || input[0] == 'N') {
            printf("Exiting programme!\n");
        }
    } while ( input[0] != 'y' && input[0] != 'n' && input[0] != 'Y' && input[0] != 'N');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's a bit complicated for me at the moment. Will come back in a few weeks and hopefully i can get my head around it. Thanks so much for you quick response.

Comment: I've keep looking at you code and i'm starting to understand it. So thanks. maybe in six months to a year i'll be able to help you! Fingers crossed!